# At what point does CUPS actually call the rasterizer in the printing process?

Tags: cups

I am trying to tap into the CUPS raster and obtain some lower level info such as pixel data, color mode, bits per pixel, bits per color, and anything else really. I can't figure out how CUPS uses the raster. Whenever I print something to PDF it never goes through any of the functions in the filter/raster.c file.

Is my approach/reasoning incorrect? I've tried printing images (png), text and PDF and the result is the same.

Comment: Does your printer understand postscript? Then either there's already a rasterized format (like PNG) or there is nothing to raster...

Comment: I didn't print to a printer, I printed using cups-pdf which generate a pdf file. If I print a text file, shouldn't that be rasterized before it gets to the printer/queue (in this case cups-pdf)?

Comment: I don't know cups' architecture. But I'd be surprised if it would. PDF is not a raster format, neither is PS ...

Comment: There's the cause of my confusion. Thanks, Felix!

Answer (score 0):

CUPS does not have any component called 'rasterizer'.

When CUPS needs to process a submitted file (you can print on the command line, like `'lp -d printername the.file'`, did you know?), ...

- ...the first thing it does is *auto-typing* the incoming file in order to determine its *mime type*;
- ...next, it checks which target print queue the user requested ('printername' in above commend); each target printer requires its own file format, which also is a mime type of its own (that is of course different for a PCL, a PostScript, an ESC/P, a GDI, a proprietary "whatever" or even a PDF-consuming printer);
- ...based on input and required final output file types of the current job, CUPS constructs an appropriate filtering chain and runs the input data through these filters.

You can follow the course of these conversions by enabling *`LogLevel debug`* in *`/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`* (restart CUPS daemon after modifying this). Then, check the log file:

```
less /var/log/cups/error_log
```

This will now show lines containing *`'Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/...'`* indicating the time when each filter in the chain is started.

The *raster/raster.c* source code file contains code which is used if the filtering chain contains any of the *ABCDtoraster* or *rastertoXYZ* filters. These filters may or may not be present on your system in the directory *`/usr/lib/cups/filter/`*, and they create or post-process a CUPS-specific raster format defined here: https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-raster.html